# Prevent teamcity from running a build with no changes

Tags: github, version-control, triggers, teamcity

I'm trying to prevent TeamCity from queueing a build that has no changes. TeamCity is queueing two builds when a PR is merged from GitHub.

My setting looks like :

[image: VCS Trigger]

[image: VCS Settings]

Any idea's ?

Here is a build summary log

[image: Build summary log]

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Comment: Have a look at this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24747#comment=27-814689. Maybe this is your case. The suggested workaround is to set internal property:
`teamcity.vcsTrigger.analyzeFullHistoryForMergeCommits=false`.
No server restart is required. Does it help?

Comment: What is triggering the extra build? (check "triggered by" in the build details)

Comment: It's being triggered by GitHub webhooks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new "Trigger Rule" that will watch for any file changes. That rule should be: "+:."

Comment: Can this be combined with GitHub webhooks?

Comment: Yes, GitHub webhooks just notify TeamCity that there is a change in the repository. Than it's up to TeamCity (and the rules you configure) to do a checkout and build.